# Is there something wrong with this java code? The result after executing is not right

Tags: java

I am a newbie in java.

Can you please tell me what is wrong with this code.
The results are not right.

I appreciate your help.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

    int x= -5 +8*6;
    int y=(55 + 9)% 9;
    int z=20 + 3 * 5/8y;
    int k = 5 +15/3 *2 -8%;

    System.out.println(x + y + z + k);
  }
}
```

Comment: What output do you expect and what output do you get instead? Also could you make sure the code in the question is the same as the code you are using? There are syntax errors in this one, you can't run it.

Answer (score 0):

This would normally be a comment. I am adding this as an answer because my suggestion, using  `repl.it` might help you resolve the problem by quick feedback.
Your code does not compile. See https://repl.it/repls/LongOrangeredLoopfusion#Main.java.

1. For simple questions such as these, please consider using tools such as `repl.it`.
2. You mention `The results is not right.` In order to help you, please state what you expect the result to be and we can possibly help you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the last two lines:

`8y` should be `8 * y` and `-8%` should be `2 % (-8)`

```
int z=20 + 3 * 5/8*y;
int k = 5 +15/3 *2 % (-8);
```

Below is the full code

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

    int x= -5 +8*6;
    int y=(55 + 9)% 9;
    int z= 20 + 3 * 5 / 8*y;
    int k = 5 +15/3 *2 % (-8);

    System.out.println(x + y + z + k);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
72
```

Answer (score 0):

The [correct solution to the exercise you're working on](https://www.w3resource.com/java-exercises/basic/java-basic-exercise-4.php) is:

```java
public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
   int w = -5 + 8 * 6;
   int x = (55 + 9) % 9;
   int y = 20 + (-3 * 5 / 8);
   int z = 5 + 15 / 3 * 2 - 8 % 3;

   System.out.print(w + "\n" + x + "\n" + y + "\n" + z);
  }
}
```

Next time, don't forget to include your *expected output* and your *actual output* in the question. Based on the information you have given it's impossible to deduce that the numbers are supposed to go on separate lines, or that you've written `+` where you need `-`.